# Acceleration and speed with gears

Tags: rotational-dynamics, differential-equations

I want to plot a graph of motion of a car with given power of the engine $P$, radius of pinion gear $r_1$, gear ratio $G_R$ between pinion and spur, wheel radius $R$ and vehicle mass $m$. I assume there are no resistive forces.

So I have $$P=mar_1G_R\omega_2=m\alpha_2\omega_2(r_1G_r)^2,$$ $\omega_2$ and \alpha_2 stand for the angular speed and angular acceleration of the spur gear. Seems like a differential equation, and when I solve it I get $$\omega_2=\frac 1{r_2G_r}\sqrt{ \frac {2Pt}{m}+C}$$, and the speed of the car is just this times $R$. The problem is that it’s not how it should work. When $G_R$ increases, acceleration decreases. What's wrong with the equations?

Edit: this is a very simplified model, we're not considering air drag, friction, weight transfer, etc.

Comment: It seems some of your variables are not defined, or notation is inconsistent. Please define your variables clearly, and use MathJax for equations. I also don't see any differential equation here.

Comment: If you have power then you do not need to gear/tire information. Acceleration is a function of power, mass and velocity $$a = \frac{P}{m v}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the acceleration as a function of engine power, and also calculate the time and displacement graphs under constant power.

$$ a = \frac{P}{m v}$$

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  t &= \int_{v_0}^v \frac{1}{a} \,{\rm d}v & x & = \int_{v_0}^v \frac{v}{a} \, {\rm d}v \\
    &= \frac{m}{2 P} \left( v^2 - v_0^2 \right) & &=\frac{m}{3 P} \left( v^3 - v_0^3 \right) \\
 v &= \sqrt{ \frac{2 P t}{m} + v_0^2 } & x & =  \frac{m}{3 P} \left( \left( \frac{2 P t}{m} + v_0^2 \right)^{3/2} - v_0^3 \right)
\end{aligned}$$

---

Building a detailed mathematical model of a car is rather complex. Even the most basic simplified version involves at least 5 interacting components, with 4 equations between them:

[image: fig1]

So to effectively answer your question you need to be more specific on which interaction(s) you are investigating (1 to 4 above), the variables involved and what is give and what is required.

Notice that to get the net force $F_{\rm net}$ (and thus the acceleration) you need to model all 4 interactions above.

A very simplified model with no clutch considerations, or mass moment of inertia of the drivetrain, or torque loss due to friction is shown below.

[image: fig2]

Start from top right and make your way to top left.

Now the addition of engine mass moment of inertia $I_E$ makes this a coupled system that cannot be solved directly in a straight forward fashion

[image: fig3]

As you can see the level of complexity quickly increases as you add details to the math model.

So it is up to you to consider all the details and all the interactions that you want in order to get the results you want.

Comment: First I want to research a simplified model. Imagine a car going on a straight line in vacuum with such tires that provide friction coefficient equal to 1. The road is smooth, so that there’s no need to put springs into suspension. It seems that the behavior of the car now follows from the behavior of the motor. Can the model be created if we know all those values that I had stated before (gear ratio, mass, power, etc.)?

Comment: Note, I fixed some issues in the figure.

Comment: Yes a model *can* be created, but the issue being how complex do you want the model to be?

Comment: My idea is to get a model which would have gear ratio as a function of time in the input, a kind of simulation of gear shifting. The simplified model is all about $a=\frac {P}{mv}$, so gear shift has no effect on it. Is that because the MMOI is not considered? By the way, I got $I=\frac {P}{\omega \dot {\omega}}$, can I substitute that into the equation? And finally, does driveline stand for the engine gear? If not, why does it have same values as the engine?

Comment: The gears affect the engine speed which dictates the power $P$ produced. You can write $$ a = \frac{T_E \omega_E}{m v} $$ from the engine torque produced and the engine speed. The gearing comes into play as the ratio between $\omega_E/v$ changes with gears.

Comment: @EvgenySizov why are you solving for MMOI? That is a given parameter. What you want to solve for is $a$ and then see if you can integrate it. See edited answer above on the two integrals you can use to get time and displacement from acceleration that is a function of velocity only.